# How to get objects from db under multiple constraints?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm trying to figure out how to get particular set of objects from database in `Django` efficiently.

I can do this using nested loops but I think that it's not a best idea.

I have models `Language` and `UserProfile` which has a property method `verified_languages` which returns a set of `Language` objects for this `UserProfile`.

What I want exactly is to create a static method of `Language` model called `get_to_languages(language)` which returns a set of all `languages` of all `UserProfiles` if these `UserProfiles` has `language` attribute in `verified_languages` property method.

So if there were there these `User`s -

```
1st. user:
name = 'Peter'
userprofile.verified_languages = ['english','german','arabic','french']

2nd. user:
name = 'Evgen'
userprofile.verified_languages = ['german','arabic','spanish']

3rd. user:
name = 'Anton'
userprofile.verified_languages = ['russian','arabic','italian']
```

And I call method `get_to_languages(Languages.objects.get(name='german'))`

It would return a set of Evgen's and Peter's languages because they know german.

Is it possible to do this using `filter`?

My old solution:

```
@staticmethod
def get_languages_to(language):
    userprofiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
    result = set()
    for up in userprofiles:
        if language in up.languages_verified:
            result.update(up.languages_verified)
    result.remove(language)
    return list(result)
```

**USERPROFILE:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', help_text=_('Related user'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Date of birth'))
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Your telephone number'))
    IBAN = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Bank account unique number'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('married', 'Married'),
        ('separated', 'Separated'),
        ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widowed', 'Widowed'),
    )

    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
        ('coincidence', u'It was coincidence'),
        ('relative_or_friends', 'From my relatives or friends'),
    )

    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True,
                                                blank=True)


    is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    language_levels = models.ManyToManyField('LanguageLevel', blank=True, related_name='translators')

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    number_of_ratings = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def languages(self):
        """
        Returns: all languages of current user include not-verified ones

        """
        return [x.language for x in self.language_levels.all()]

    @property
    def languages_verified(self):
        """
        Returns: verified languages of current user

        """
        return [x.language for x in self.language_levels.exclude(level__name='unknown')]

    def passive_skill(self, language):
        """
        True if user has at least passive skill (lowest level) of the language
        Args:
            language: Language object

        Returns: Bool

        """
        if language in self.languages_verified:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Does `Language` have m2m relationship with `UserProfile`?

Comment: No, it hasn't explicitly. It has m2m to LanguageLevel model which has Language as a Foreign key. I've added UserProfile at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it could be done this way: first, get all `LanguageLevel` that contains current language and their `level_name` is not `unknown`, then get all userprofiles from the result `LanguageLevel`. In the end, get all languages linked to these userprofiles(apparently it's untested, but please try it out):

```
language_levels = LanguageLevel.objects.filter(language=language) \
                                       .exclude(level__name='unknown')

userprofiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(language_levels__in=language_levels)

all_languages = profiles.values_list('language_levels__language', 
                                         flat=True).distinct()
```

Note that the `__in` is very inefficient but that's if you don't have huge amount of records it should be OK. Just pay attention to the performance and see if that goes well.

Comment: By the way, you could use `through` keyword to define m2m relationship between `UserProfile` and `Language`. It saves one level of relationship from django perspective: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through.